# Writing nested loops on a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

I have some code to calculate the width of a grid I have in a 2d array. I would like to calculate the width in a single line using nested loops.

I have tried this:

```py
width = [(row, col) for row in grid for col in row width +=1 break]
```

Heres the code I know works:

```py
for row in grid:
    for col in row:
        width += 1
    break
```

I'm very confused as to how to write this on one line, thats if it is even possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you interrupt the outer loop after the first iteration, why do you need it in the first place??

Comment: Does the `break` is correctly indented ?

Comment: You should use list comprehension (the thing you tried) unless you plan to use the resulting list.  It is not just a way to right one liner `for` loops.

Comment: Could you provide a sample input and output for your question?

Answer (score 2):

Just to be sure: we are talking about simple python arrays, right?

Question two: all rows have the same number of columns? The `break` command in the working approach would suggest so.

If it's a 'yes' for both questions, you could actually just do something like this:

```
my_grid = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
print(len(my_grid[0])) # prints '4'
```